# Join two queries of same table

Tags: mysql

> I want to join the result of below meantioned queries

```
SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` FROM chat where USER_NAME='user1' group by `CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` ORDER BY `chat`.`CURRENT_DATE_TIME` DESC 

SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` FROM chat where CHAT_COUNTERPARTY='user1' group by `USER_NAME` ORDER BY `chat`.`CURRENT_DATE_TIME` DESC
```

> Result after UNION of both result is

```
 idCHAT     USER_NAME   TEXT    CURRENT_DATE_TIME Descending    CHAT_COUNTERPARTY   
 6  user1   helSSSSSSlooooo     2014-10-17 20:45:22     user3
 4  user3   helSSSSSSlooooo     2014-10-17 20:44:00     user1
 3  user2   helSSSSSSlooooo     2014-10-17 20:43:59     user1
 1  user1   helSSSSSSlooooo     2014-10-17 20:40:41     user2
```

> But I want only idCHAT 6&3 from the table because user3 & user2 are CHAT_COUNTERPARTY of user1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY`, if(USER_NAME='user1',`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY`,`USER_NAME`)as party from(SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` FROM chat where USER_NAME='".$user."' group by `CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` UNION (SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` FROM chat where CHAT_COUNTERPARTY='user1' group by `USER_NAME`) ORDER BY `CURRENT_DATE_TIME` DESC)res group by party order by `CURRENT_DATE_TIME` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union keyword

```
SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` 
FROM chat 
where USER_NAME='user1' 
group by `CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` 
UNION
(SELECT `idCHAT`,`USER_NAME`,`TEXT`,`CURRENT_DATE_TIME`,`CHAT_COUNTERPARTY` 
FROM chat 
where CHAT_COUNTERPARTY='user1' 
group by `USER_NAME`)
ORDER BY `CURRENT_DATE_TIME` DESC
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @pritinarang I just edited answer. Just move order by to the end, after both query.

Comment: still error:- #1250 - Table 'chat' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: @pritinarang try again with this query, without 'chat' in order by.

Comment: I edited the question please check my exect requirement UNION successfully done.